# Having trouble enabling vertical scrolling in edit box

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, mfc

I'm using Visual Studio 2005 and programming a dialog-based MFC application in C++.

I have an `edit box` and I'm trying to make it `auto-scroll`.
When I make auto `vscroll` true, it still won't `auto-scroll` when I have too many lines in my `edit box`.

Any ideas in what could be wrong? Is there maybe some code line I have to add to my `edit box`?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "Auto-Scroll"?

Turning on auto vscroll enables the [ES_AUTOVSCROLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775464.aspx) edit control style which:

> ES_AUTOVSCROLL - 
>       Automatically scrolls text up one page when the user presses the ENTER key on the last line.

This may not be what you think "Auto-Scroll" means.  A common misconception is that auto vscroll will automatically turn on/off the vertical scroll bar as more text is typed into the edit control.  This is not the case, you have to either always have the scroll bar displayed or you have to come up with your own code to turn on and off the scroll bar yourself.

Comment: No, it should work without any code.  You have to say that you want a scroll bar.  If there is nothing to scroll, it will display disabled.  It's just how the builtin win32 controls work by default.  What you have to code for is if you want to automatically display or hide the scroll bar when it's needed or not.

Comment: You can set `Auto-HScroll` and `Auto-VScroll` on property tab in resource window, but at the first, you have to set `Horizontal Scroll` and `Vertical Scroll` to enable.